# Script Size Limit in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

For example: how many lines of

insert into foo ( '1','2' )

could one have in a file. I remember it being around 100k but searching with google has proved fruitless thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article on how to specify the script size at which IntelliSense functionality is disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964729.aspx) you are allowed more than 2MB, in SQL Server 2008 at least.

Comment: @blasto was that a SSIS package? This question is about script size, not package size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a hard limit, my largest file, generated by the Database Publisher is around 270K and that runs fine.